# Changing Variable Names in SAS on Imported Data

Tags: variables, sas, renaming

I am working on a part of a piece of a program that is designed to standardize certain variable names. I often get lists with similar, but different variable names. First name could be first_name, fname, first, etc...

I have the logic of the standardization, but I need guidance on how to implement it. It seems like it should be fairly simple. If the name of variable1 is 'first_name' or 'fname' or 'first' then rename variable1 to First_name.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to treat this as a data transformation problem, probably using a format.

First, get the variable names into a dataset.  `PROC CONTENTS` with an `OUT` can do this, or you can use the preexisting `dictionary.columns` or `sashelp.vcolumn` as I will below.  Then apply a format to them (that you create) that modifies names, and anything that is modified will be used in a rename statement.

First, create a dataset, either by hand in SAS or (better) in Excel/something else and import it.

```
data refmts;
input start $ label $;
start=upcase(start);
fmtname='$VarFmt';
datalines;
first_Name fname
firstName fname
f_name fname
last_name lname
lastName lname
l_name lname
;;;;
run;

proc format cntlin=refmts;
quit;
```

Then import your file, let's assume you imported it as `WORK.MYDATA`.  Now we'll see if there are any reformattable names.  This is untested so might be syntactically off in one or two places but should show how to approach this.

```
data need_reformat;
set sashelp.vcolumn;
where memname='MYDATA' and libname='WORK';
if put(name,$VarFmt.) ne name then do;
  rename = catx(' ','rename',name,'=',put(name,$varfmt.),';');
  output;
end;
run;

proc sql;
select rename
 into :renamelist separated by ' '
 from need_reformat;
quit;

data want;
set work.mydata;
&renamelist.;
run;
```